# Storing a hash in a hash

Tags: perl, hash

I'm having troubles with a Perl script. I try to store a hash in a hash. The script is trivial:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %h1=();
$h1{name}="parent";
my %h2=();
$h2{name}="child";

$h1{nested}=%h2; # store hash h2 in hash h1

print "h2:\n";
print Dumper(%h2); # works
print "h1{nested}:\n";
print Dumper($h1{nested}); # fails
```

The results:

```
h2:
$VAR1 = 'name';
$VAR2 = 'child';
h1{nested}:
$VAR1 = '1/8';
```

Why is the $h1{nested} not dumped as a hash, but as some kind of weird scalar (1/8)?

PS: even if this question sounds trivial - I searched SO but did not find that it was asked before. 
PPS: my Perl is v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 53 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: thanks everyone for the great answers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only store a **hashref** in a hash:

```
$h1{nested}=\%h2;
```

and then you would access `%h2`'s name by doing

```
$h1{nested}->{name}
```

In your code, %h2 is forced to scalar context, which shows you that "1/8" value, and stores that.

Comment: or `$h1{nested}{name}`; see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 5):

In perl the values stored in a *list* (hash or array) are **always scalars**. Given this, the only way to store a hash inside another hash is to store a reference to it.

```
$h1{'nested'} = \%h2;
```

or also

```
$h1{'nested'} = { 'name'=>'child' };
```

(the braces in the right hand side is a reference to an anonymous hash).

BTW, to not quote the literals in the keys is usually considered bad practice, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401556/are-quotes-around-hash-keys-a-good-practice-in-perl)

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the $h1{nested} not dumped as a hash, but as some kind of weird scalar (1/8)?

Because you're storing it in a *scalar* context!

When you do this:

```
$h1{nested} = %h2;
```

You're storing a scalar. Since `%h2` is a hash, you're given the ol' *fraction string*. According to the [Perldoc website](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-values)

> *If you evaluate a hash in scalar context, it returns false if the hash is empty. If there are any key/value pairs, it returns true; more precisely, the value returned is a string consisting of the number of used buckets and the number of allocated buckets, separated by a slash.*

That explains the `1/8` you're getting.

What you need to do is store the hash as a **reference** in the other hash. As others pointed out, it should be:

```
$h1{nested} = \%h2;
```

The backslash before the hash's name gives you the memory location where the hash is stored. You can use the curly braces, but I prefer the backslash notation.

Take a look at [`perldoc prelreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) on your computer (or on the webpage I've linked to). This will tell you how to make such things as a list of lists, hashes or hashes, lists of hashes, and hashes of lists. Just a *word o` warning*: If you get too complex, it'll be hard to maintain, so once you've had your fun, take a look at [perldoc's Perl Object Orientation Programming Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html).

The `perldoc` command contains lots of Perl documentation including for all Perl function, Perl modules installed on your system, and even basic information about the Perl language.