# Setup Environment variable using perl

Tags: perl, variables, environment, tcsh

I am trying to set environment variable using Perl. It should export this variable outside (in current shell) not just in the script.

I tried:

```
`setenv X1 /p/fsd`

system("setenv X1 /p/fsd") == 0 or die "failed:$?"

system command "setenv X1 /p/fsd" failed: -1

$ENV{"X1"} = "/p/fsd";
```

Nothing seems to be working.

If it matters i am using TCSH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting an environment variable through a Perl script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192682/setting-an-environment-variable-through-a-perl-script)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$ENV{"X1"} = "/p/fsd";
```

is the right way.

Test in [`perlconsole`](http://sukria.net/perlconsole.html) :

```
Perl> $ENV{X1} = "/p/fsd";
/p/fsd

Perl> system('echo $X1');
/p/fsd
0
```

**NOTE**

- the single quotes (or backslashing) is required on `echo $X1` to prevent `perl` to interpolate it itself.
- you can't change ENV of parent shell, see http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=684685

Comment: This will only work while script is running, right? Once script stops they are gone.  What i am trying to do is i have 10-15 environment variable in the SHELL and they update frequently. So instead of me setting them manually.. i was thinking to script it.

Comment: This is the principle of the subshell. If you kill the father, you kill the son too, this is sad, but this is life.

Comment: Added link for explanations about subshells and parents.

Comment: yeah.. in that case i might have to change shell and use Bash and try to script using shell scripting since tcsh is brain dead for scripting.

Comment: Thanks... for opening my eyes... :) i thought there has to be a way but doesn't look like using perl....

Answer (score 7):

Equally important to know how to set an env variable is how to delete it:

```
delete $ENV{"X1"};
```

This will delete the environment variable for the perl process and any children processes. But the environment variable will still be set for the parent process.

Comment: Should it be *"X1"* or *X1*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Those are equivalent.  In general, we leave out the quotes because it is simpler.  Especially with environment variables because they are all caps and no special characters.  It is possible that quotes are necessary if you are using weird special characters.  See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401556/are-quotes-around-hash-keys-a-good-practice-in-perl)

Answer (score 3):

Because there's no special characters in `setenv X1 /p/fsd`,

```
system("setenv X1 /p/fsd")
```

is equivalent to

```
system("setenv", "X1", "/p/fsd")
```

It's failing because there's is no program named `setenv`. If this optimisation didn't exist, you get a different result*. In that case,

```
system("setenv X1 /p/fsd")
```

would be equivalent to

```
system("sh", "-c", "setenv X1 /p/fsd")
```

That wouldn't work either because `sh` has no `setenv` command. So you could run the following instead:

```
system("tcsh", "-c", "setenv X1 /p/fsd")
```

But it would be pointless. You'd create a shell, set one of its variables. Then the shell exits and its variables cease to exist.

If you want to set a env var seen by Perl and its children, simply use

```
$ENV{X1} = "/p/fsd";         # Until end of program
```

or

```
local $ENV{X1} = "/p/fsd";   # Until end of scope
```

---

* — Optimised code shouldn't behave differently than unoptimised code, but since the optimisation just changes what error you get, it's acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

As other replies have mentioned, you can't set an environment variable in the parent from the child.  However, you could do something complicated in perl and then pass the end result back to the shell to be set.  For example, in `tcsh`:

```
eval `perl -le 'print q(setenv X1 /p/fsd)'`
```

You could make this feel a bit more transparent with, e.g.,

```
alias x1.pl 'eval `x1.pl`'
```

Comment: `ssh-agent` has the same problem (setting environment variables in the calling shell) and uses the same `eval` trick. It has even switches for the different setenv syntaxes in `sh` and `csh` (`-s` resp. `-c`).