# Setting an environment variable through a Perl script

Tags: linux, perl, bash, sh

I am trying to set an environment variable, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, through a Perl script in the following way:

I have created `.profile` under `/root`

`.profile` has an `export` command say:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/
```

My Perl script is `test.pl` and it has:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system(". /root/.profile");
```

When I execute `./test.pl`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't change the environment of another process.

Comment: You can only change the environment of the process itself. This environment will then be inherited by child processes it spawns. Since `system()` runs the shell command in a child process of perl, any environment changes it makes will not affect perl, and will not affect the shell that invoked perl.

Comment: So how can i change env variable in perl script?

Answer (score 12):

Your current script doesn't even change an environment variable in the Perl script itself. Rather, it invokes a shell as a subprocess; that shell process executes `. /root/.profile`, which updates `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only in that shell process.

You can change an environment variable in a Perl script (more precisely, in the process running the Perl script) by updating `%ENV`:

```
$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = '/'; # or some more reasonable value
```

As `perldoc -v %ENV` says:

> `%ENV` The hash `%ENV` contains your current environment. Setting a value in "ENV" changes the environment for any child processes you subsequently "`fork()`" off.

But that probably still won't do what you want; it won't (and can't) affect the environment of the process that invokes the Perl script (your interactive shell), only the Perl process itself and anything it invokes.

I'll assume you want to update `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your current interactive shell process. To do that, you can have you Perl script *print a shell command* that will update `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Then, rather than simply running your Perl script, you can execute it and then evaluate its output. For example:

```
$ cat env.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/\n";
$ ./env.pl          # just prints the command without executing it
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/
$ eval $(./env.pl)  # executes the command in the current shell
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/
$
```

This assumes that your current shell is bash or something similar.

Another option: After modifying `%ENV`, your Perl script can invoke another command, even a new interactive shell. The new process will inherit its environment from the Perl script. This can be a bit cumbersome, though; for example, if the new process is an interactive shell, it won't inherit *unexported* variables or history from the parent shell.

(One note, not directly related to your question: The fact that you're messing with `/root/.profile` implies that you're doing things as `root` (superuser). This can be dangerous. Use the `root` account (either by logging into it or via `sudo` only for things that actually need root privileges. For anything else, use a personal user account.

Comment: Hey Can I call eval($./env.pl) from another perl script say test.pl using system command if so Can you explain me how?

Comment: @user2848437: Not with that syntax. Perl does have a syntax for capturing the output of an external command, using backticks or `qx/string/` (`perldoc perlop` and search for "Quote-Like Operators"). And it has an `eval` function (`perldoc -f eval`) -- but of course Perl's `eval` requires an argument with Perl syntax, not shell syntax. But there are better ways to invoke Perl code from a Perl script: put the code in a module and call it, or just copy the code into your script.

Answer (score 5):

To change the environment in a Perl script, assign to the `%ENV` hash:

```
$ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'} = '/';
```

If you want to write a program that's used by a shell to change its environment, the way this is generally done is to have the script write shell commands to stdout. The shell then executes this with command substitution and uses `eval` to execute the resulting commands:

Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\n';
```

Shell script:

```
eval "$(/path/to/perlscript)"
```

For examples of commands that work like this, see [`tset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tset) and [`ssh-agent`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent).

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/perl                                  $ENV{'LD_LIBRARY_PATH'} = '/';`              in test.pl and executed ./test.pl still LD_LIBRARY_PATH remains same

Comment: That's because changing the environment in a perl script will not do anything to the environment of the shell that started your perl script.

Comment: You asked _how can i change env variable in perl script?_ My answer changes the environment WITHIN the perl script, it doesn't change the environment in the parent shell. As I said in a comment, and others explained in their answers, you can't change the environment in another process -- you can only change it in your own process, and it will be inherited by children.

Answer (score 5):

`system` starts a new process, and changing the environment there won't affect the environment in the process of your script (usually—there are generally os-dependent means of changing other processes' environments).

The environment in a perl program is associated with `%ENV`, which is kind of like (it isn't actually) a tied hash to the environment: changing it will change the environment. Thus:

```
$ENV{LD_LIBRARY_PATH} = '/';
```

Answer (score 3):

This can now be done with the [`Env::Modify` module](http://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify):

```
use Env::Modify 'source';
source("/root/.profile");
... env settings of .profile are now available to Perl ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it.

This is from [the Perl FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.3/perlfaq8.html):

> In the strictest sense, it can't be done--the script executes as a different process from the shell it was started from. Changes to a process are not reflected in its parent--only in any children created after the change. There is shell magic that may allow you to fake it by eval()ing the script's output in your shell; check out the comp.unix.questions FAQ for details.